# Catalina & Big Sur Notifications: iPhone in Use: This iPhone is in use by another user on this Mac

Tags: iphone, ipad, catalina, big-sur

Got a new odd notification after "upgrading" to Catalina (10.15.2) that's never manifested before in Mojave or previous releases.  This happens with both iPhones and iPads even though there are no other users logged into this Mac concurrently:

[image: example]

Any idea as to the ramifications of this message or how to eliminate it properly (I'm guessing I can find something about it in the Notifications' settings, but I'd prefer to get to the root of the issue)?

UPDATE:

The same issue exists in Big Sur:

[image: big sur still]

And it progressively goes further down the path of insanity:
[image: many more repeated messages]

Comment: Have you changed your Apple ID, or your Mac user account recently?

Comment: @benwiggy no, unfortunately...

Comment: I would try turning the iPhone and iPad off for a bit, then restart the Mac while the devices are off.

Comment: @benwiggy the problem is that we have several all associated with this system and that's not an option due to some various dynamics in the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation has proven overwhelming at times with an enormous number of notifications.

While this is not a solution, one can simply issue `killall NotificationCenter` from the shell (`Terminal.app`, `iTerm`, etc) to clear out the queue of notifications quickly to restore a tiny bit of sanity.

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it answers your problem as you said. It avoids it being bumped by Community bot as unsolved.