# What app (system or otherwise) does this "IPHONE IN USE" icon belong to? Or where does it live on the Big Sur filesystem?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, big-sur, icon

As a followup to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/379634/13220) in better understanding what is causing the notification to show up in the Notification Center, I want to isolate the app or system process that's issuing this notification.

The icon that is appearing in the notification center is the following (blown up quite a bit for help in recognition):

[image: notification icon]

In context it comes from this notification:

[image: context]

What is this icon/image from? If no one knows, where is it on the filesystem?

Comment: Pretty sure that’s a placeholder icon, used when there’s an issue loading the expected icon (or when one wasn’t configured).

Comment: In previous macOS it looked like what I linked to in the previous reference post. Are you thinking it's no longer that "Application" icon now in Big Sur?

Comment: I can’t speak to this particular situation, unfortunately. My suggestion would be to reach out to Apple support directly.

Comment: I suppose I'll have to trawl through all images on the filesystem to see if I can isolate this. Apple support is usually worse than hitting a wall with about one or two steps back in terms of time and energy go. I've had their support and "geniuses" tell me so many times now that I'm so far ahead of them that they just laugh and part ways. 